# How to create a seperate navigation Drawer for different users : React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have an application in which I have 3 drawer items in a custom drawer function. I have a login page as the main component. What I'm trying to do is to display a specific drawer for admin users and a specific drawer for normal users. I have searched In a number of blogs and documentation and couldn't find anything very useful.

```
AdminDrawer: Account, Dashboard etc

UserDrawer: Profile, Contact etc
```

I have tried to achieve this using many methods. I have firebase login and I'm checking user based on TextInput and sending them to corresponding pages. I'm trying to hide some items for normal users.

Here is my

```
DrawerNavigator.js
```

```
const DrawerContent = (props) => (

    <Container>
        <Header style={styles.header}>
            <Body>
                <Image
                    style={styles.head_image}
                    source={require('../assets/logo.png')}
                />
            </Body>
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </Content>
    </Container>
)

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(

    {
    Admin: {
        screen: Admin,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Account",
            drawerIcon: () => (
                <Ionicons name="md-home" style={styles.icon} size={20} />
            )
        }
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Register a user",
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Ionicons name="md-person-add" style={styles.icon} size={20} />
            )
        }
    },
    UserPage: {
        screen: User,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "User",
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Ionicons name="md-person-add" style={styles.icon} size={20} />
            )
        }
    }
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Admin',
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: DrawerContent,
        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    }
);
```

And here is my

```
AppNavigator.js
```

```
export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        Auth: Login,
        Main:DrawerNavigator,
    })
);
```

And in the

```
Login.js
```

I'm doing the login authentication something like,

```
handleLogin = () => {
      const { email , password } = this.state;
      firebase.auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(() => {

          })
          .catch(error => alert(error))
    }
```

I would like to hide some drawer items from the normal user or show separate drawer for admin and normal user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use switch navigation for this case.

```
const mainSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Admin: {
    screen: AdminDrawer,
  },
  User: {
    screen: UserDrawer,
  }
});
```

And update `handleLogin` to this:

```
handleLogin = () => {
  const { email , password } = this.state;
  firebase.auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      if(email == "admin@user.com"){
        this.setState({role:"admin"})
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Admin')
      } else if(email == "normaluser@user.com") {
        this.setState({role:"admin"})
        this.props.navigation.navigate('User')
      }
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dear. It worked! Concept of SwitchNavigator, StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator cleared now.